# Бум! Как нарисовать и анимировать бомбу?

Tags: css, svg, canvas, webgl, gsap

У меня есть такой код:

```css
/*Бомба*/

.bomb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 15%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}


/*Фитиль*/

.wick {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% - 0.1vw);
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 40%;
  border-left: 0.5vw solid brown;
}
```

```html
<!--Бомба-->
<div class="bomb">
  <!--Фитиль-->
  <div class="wick">
  </div>
</div>
```

Как нарисовать бомбу, как на картинке ниже, и как анимировать взрыв бомбы?

[image: Изображение бомбы]

Приветствуется использование любых других, кроме как только CSS, средств и технологий для рисования и создания эффекта анимации и трансформации, указанных в метках вопроса?

Answer (score 7):

Вариант CSS

Просто нажать на красную кнопку, и будет БУМ!

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var bomb = document.getElementsByClassName('bomb');
var wick = document.getElementsByClassName('wick');
var veil = document.getElementsByClassName('veil');
var fire = document.getElementsByClassName('fire_container');
btn[0].onclick = function() {
  this.classList.add('btn__active');
  bomb[0].classList.add("bomb__active");
  wick[0].classList.add("wick__active");
  veil[0].classList.add("veil__active");
  fire[0].classList.add("fire_container__active");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

body:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  clip-path: polygon( 40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 10%, 40% 0, 22% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 50%, 12% 0, 9% 0, 100% 80%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 7% 0, 5% 0, 50% 100%, 20% 100%, 3% 0, 1% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}


/*Бомба*/

.bomb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 15%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #888;
  box-shadow: inset -20px -20px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 100px black;
}

.bomb__active {
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 0%;
  border-radius: 0%;
  animation: 7s linear bomb;
}

@keyframes bomb {
  0% {
    right: 7%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 15%;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  98.9% {
    right: 7%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 15%;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    right: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 15%;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 0%;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
}

.bomb:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bomb:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 28%;
  width: 48%;
  height: 18%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.1) skew(-5deg, 0deg);
}


/*Фитиль*/

.wick {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% - 0.1vw);
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 40%;
  border-left: 0.5vw solid brown;
  border-top: 0.5vw solid brown;
  border-radius: 70% 0% 0 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.wick__active {
  width: calc(0% + 1vw);
  padding-top: 0%;
  animation: 5s linear wick;
}

@keyframes wick {
  0% {
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
  45% {
    width: calc(0% + 1vw);
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(0% + 1vw);
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}


/*Огонь*/

.fire_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: -53%;
  left: 64%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.fire_container__active {
  top: -14%;
  left: 44%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 5s linear fire_container;
}

@keyframes fire_container {
  0% {
    top: -53%;
    left: 64%;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    opacity: 1;
    zoom: 3;
  }
  5% {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  49% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  49.001% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    top: -48%;
    left: 44%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  99.9% {
    top: -14%;
    left: 44%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fire {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-name: fire;
  animation-duration: 3ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.fire_flame {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
}

.fire_flame_red {
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: OrangeRed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px OrangeRed;
}

.fire_flame_orange {
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px orange;
}

.fire_flame_yellow {
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px gold;
}

.fire_flame_white {
  left: 35%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px white;
}

.fire_circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.fire_circle {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  left: 45.5%;
  bottom: 10%;
  background: SlateBlue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px SlateBlue;
}

@keyframes fire {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(1deg) scaleY(1.04);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) scaleY(0.92);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
}


/*Завеса*/

.veil {
  display: none;
}

.veil__active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  animation: 7.2s linear veil;
}

@keyframes veil {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.veil__active span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.5vw;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2vw;
  transform: scale3d(4, 4, 1) skewX(40deg) rotate(-20deg);
  animation: 11s linear veil_span;
}

@keyframes veil_span {
  0% {
    font-size: 0vw;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    font-size: 0vw;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(360deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(360deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  99% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) skewX(0deg) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 2vw;
    transform: scale3d(4, 4, 1) skewX(40deg) rotate(-20deg);
  }
}


/*Кнопка*/

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 5%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background-color: #888;
  box-shadow: inset -20px -20px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 100px black;
}

.btn {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  background-color: darkred;
  box-shadow: inset -20px -20px 100px darkred, 10px 10px 20px #222, inset 0px 0px 100px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: height 0.1s;
}

.btn__active {
  height: 54%;
}
```

```html
<!--Бомба-->
<div class="bomb">
  <!--Фитиль-->
  <div class="wick">
  </div>
  <!--Огонь-->
  <div class="fire_container">
    <div class="fire">
      <div class="fire_flame_red fire_flame"></div>
      <div class="fire_flame_orange fire_flame"></div>
      <div class="fire_flame_yellow fire_flame"></div>
      <div class="fire_flame_white fire_flame"></div>
      <div class="fire_circle_blue fire_circle"></div>
      <div class="fire_circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Кнопка-->
<div class="button">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
<!--Завеса-->
<div class="veil"><span>Бум</span></div>
```

*Помним и не забываем, что жить в мире — это самое важное, что может быть на Земле.*

Comment: В целях безопасности жизни необходимо добавить разминирование бомбы!