# Как нарисовать спичку на CSS не изменяя HTML?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть html код:

```
    <div class="match">
        <div class="fire"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="stick"></div>
    </div>
```

Какие нужно добавить css стили, при этом не изменяя html код, чтобы получилась спичка как на картинке? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8):

Вот такая получилась спичка. Похоже?

```css
.match {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1.1);
}

.fire {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffb105, #ff0e01);
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.stick {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  bottom: -90%;
  left: 45%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8c4816, #f0a15f);
  border: 0.1vw solid #c2573e;
}

.stick::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  left: -48%;
  top: -10%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 22%;
  background: #4d260f;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.stick::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  left: -68%;
  top: -14%;
  width: 240%;
  height: 22%;
  background: #f4f3f3;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff 10%, transparent);
  filter: blur(0.5vw);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <!--Не пригодился<div class="top"></div>-->
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

п.с. Если будет нужно, то [бомба здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235459/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BC-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83)

Comment: Похоже на моё, хотя элементов поменьше. Не пойму, чего так много отрицательных координат. PS: бомба в тему)))

Answer (score 5):

Сначала кладём картинку и обводим контуры всех интересующих нас элементов. Можно даже сделать responsive. При необходимости используем border-radius.

Самое интересное - огонь в форме капли: тоже используем border-radius для всех углов кроме одного, потом поворачиваем на 45 градусов углом наверх. Угол на картинке явно острый, так что закладываем, что после поворота надо будет сжать фигуру по горизонтальной оси и делаем её чуть крупнее. У меня не получилось прям идеально повторить форму, но думаю, что вышло достаточно точно. Помимо этого у огня должна быть градиентная тень, а просто тенью такое не сделать, поэтому я делаю из псевдоэлементов сразу 2 фигуры огня, одну из которых собираюсь при заливке размыть через blur и использовать вместо тени. Делаю два псевдоэлемента без основного, чтобы не создавать контекст позиционирования и не позиционировать псевдоэлемент относительно него.

Для головки тоже добавляем псевдоэлемент, который станет бликом внутри неё, а внешнее свечение сделаем тенью. Хотя, наверное, тут я перемудрил и можно было обойтись дополнительным радиальным градиентом, но переделывать уже не буду.

Итак, вот фигуры и остаётся их только раскрасить:

```css
body {
  margin: 1vh auto;
  max-width: 35vmin;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.match::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyVS0.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: .5;
}

.match {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 272%;
}

.match > * {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.stick {
  top: 45%;
  bottom: .5%;
  width: 12%;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

.top {
  top: 37%;
  bottom: 51.5%;
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50% / 80% 80% 20% 20%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.fire::before, .fire::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 52%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: scaleX(.9) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Раскрашиваем, добавляем z-index, тени и увеличиваем область свечения (в принципе, можно было размеры поменять, но я просто добавил transform). К сожалению, фильтры нельзя применять в процентах, так что для адекватного результата я применил rem.

```css
html {
  font-size: .952vmin;
}

body {
  margin: 1vh auto;
  max-width: 35vmin;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.match {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 272%;
}

.match > * {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.stick {
  top: 45%;
  bottom: .5%;
  width: 12%;
  border: 1px solid #A34639;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A34639, #E5A56B);
  z-index: -1;
}

.top {
  top: 37%;
  bottom: 51.5%;
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #472814;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -.5rem 3rem white);
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50% / 80% 80% 20% 20%;
  background: white;
  filter: blur(.8rem);
  transform: scale(2);
}

.fire::before, .fire::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 52%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(.9) rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EFE33E, #E73625);
}

.fire::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.match {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.stick {
  background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 151, 0, 1) 100%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: -50px auto;
}

.top {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 5px 10px white;
  margin: -100px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(93, 74, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.fire {
  background: rgb(236, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(223, 160, 0, 1) 79%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 52% 52% 49% 51% / 64% 64% 39% 36%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #ec6060;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```