# Как нарисовать и анимировать спичку?

Tags: css3, svg, canvas, webgl, gsap

Меня заинтересовала [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246387/377637) участника [@Qwertiy♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), где он нарисовал спичку с использованием технологии CSS.

Вот его [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246387/377637) на вопрос [Как нарисовать спичку на CSS не изменяя HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1246262/377637):

```css
html {
  font-size: .952vmin;
}

body {
  margin: 1vh auto;
  max-width: 35vmin;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.match {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 272%;
}

.match>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.stick {
  top: 45%;
  bottom: .5%;
  width: 12%;
  border: 1px solid #A34639;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A34639, #E5A56B);
  z-index: -1;
}

.top {
  top: 37%;
  bottom: 51.5%;
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #472814;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -.5rem 3rem white);
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50% / 80% 80% 20% 20%;
  background: white;
  filter: blur(.8rem);
  transform: scale(2);
}

.fire::before,
.fire::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 52%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(.9) rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EFE33E, #E73625);
}

.fire::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Автор: [@Qwertiy♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy)

**Вопрос:** возможно ли нарисовать и воспроизвести анимацию зажженной спички, используя любые средства и технологии для рисования и создания эффекта анимации и трансформации, указанные в метках вопроса?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на основе [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246341/377637), с использованием всё той же технологии — CSS.

Анимация начинается после нажатия на кнопку и занимает полный процесс сгорания спички.

```js
var fire_flame = document.getElementsByClassName('.fire_flame'); document.querySelector('.start').onclick = function() {this.setAttribute('disabled', true); document.querySelector('.sulfur').classList.add('sulfur__active'); var fire_flame = document.querySelectorAll('.fire_flame'); for (var i = 0; i < fire_flame.length; i++) {fire_flame[i].className += " fire_flame__active";} document.querySelector('.fire').classList.add('fire__active'); document.querySelector('.ember').classList.add('ember__active'); document.querySelector('.wick').classList.add('wick__active');}
```

```css
.fire_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.fire {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  bottom: 55%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

@keyframes fire {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(1deg) scaleY(1.05);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) scaleY(0.90);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
}

.fire__active {
  animation: 3ms fire ease-in infinite alternate 200ms, 10s fire_active linear forwards 1s;
  /*animation-duration: 3ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;*/
}

@keyframes fire_active {
  0% {
    bottom: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -2%;
  }
}

.fire_flame {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0, 0);
}

.fire_flame__active {
  /*transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);*/
  animation: 0.5s fire_flame__active forwards, 0.5s fire_flame__deactive forwards 11s;
}

@keyframes fire_flame__active {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0, 0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  }
}

@keyframes fire_flame__deactive {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0, 0);
  }
}

.fire_flame_red {
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: OrangeRed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px OrangeRed;
}

.fire_flame_orange {
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px orange;
}

.fire_flame_yellow {
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px gold;
}

.fire_flame_white {
  left: 37.5%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px white;
}

.sulfur {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 41%;
  bottom: 6%;
  width: 18%;
  height: 20%;
  /*background: SlateBlue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px slateblue;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #472814;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);
}

.sulfur__active {
  border: none;
  background: SlateBlue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px slateblue;
  animation: 0.5s sulfur__deactive forwards 12s;
}

@keyframes sulfur__deactive {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1) translateY(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1) translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0, 0) translateY(100%);
  }
}

.wick {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 58%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 9.1%;
  background: chocolate;
  border: 0.2vw solid brown;
}

.wick__active {
  animation: 10s wick__active linear forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes wick__active {
  0% {
    height: 58%;
    border: 0.2vw solid brown;
  }
  99.99% {
    height: 0;
    border: 0.2vw solid brown;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}

.ember {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 58%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 9.5%;
  border-left: 1.25vw solid black;
}

.ember__active {
  animation: 12s ember__active linear forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes ember__active {
  0% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 58%;
    border-left: 1.25vw solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  1% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 70%;
    border-left: 1.25vw solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  99% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 70%;
    border-left: 1.25vw solid black;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    height: 4%;
    border-left: 15vw solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="fire_container">
  <div class="fire">
    <div class="fire_flame_red fire_flame"></div>
    <div class="fire_flame_orange fire_flame"></div>
    <div class="fire_flame_yellow fire_flame"></div>
    <div class="fire_flame_white fire_flame"></div>
    <div class="sulfur"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ember"></div>
  <div class="wick"></div>
</div>

<button class="start">Зажечь спичку</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ на основе ответа участника @Qwertiy♦, с использованием всё той же технологии — CSS.

Для начала немного видоизменим изображение спички. Чтобы огонь от нее казался более реалистичным, для этого добавим дополнительно еще несколько элементов:

```css
html {
  font-size: .952vmin;
}

body {
  margin: 1vh auto;
  max-width: 35vmin;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.match {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 272%;
}

.match>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.stick {
  top: 45%;
  bottom: .5%;
  width: 12%;
  border: 1px solid #A34639;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A34639, #E5A56B);
  z-index: -1;
}

.top {
  top: 35%;
  bottom: 51.5%;
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: SlateBlue;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -.5rem 3rem white) blur(0.5rem);
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50% / 80% 80% 20% 20%;
  background: white;
  filter: blur(.8rem);
  transform: scale(2);
}

.fire_red::before,
.fire_red::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 52%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(.9) rotate(45deg);
  background: OrangeRed;
}

.fire_red::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_orange::before,
.fire_orange::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 48.5%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.85) scaleY(0.8) rotate( 45deg);
  background: orange;
}

.fire_orange::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_yellow::before,
.fire_yellow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 44.5%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.75) scaleY(0.6) rotate( 45deg);
  background: gold;
}

.fire_yellow::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_white::before,
.fire_white::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 40%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.4) scaleY(0.4) rotate( 45deg);
  background: white;
}

.fire_white::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire_red"></div>
  <div class="fire_orange"></div>
  <div class="fire_yellow"></div>
  <div class="fire_white"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

А теперь, отвечая на заданный вопрос, добавим легкую анимацию. С помощью правила `@keyframes` для всех вместе взятых элементов, которые составляют огонь, установим общие ключевые кадры и включим в них свойства трансформации для воспроизведения эффекта анимации зажженной спички.

Результат такой несложной анимации оказался следующим:

```css
html {
  font-size: .952vmin;
}

body {
  margin: 1vh auto;
  max-width: 35vmin;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.match {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 272%;
}

.match>*,
.fire>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.stick {
  top: 45%;
  bottom: .5%;
  width: 12%;
  border: 1px solid #A34639;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A34639, #E5A56B);
  z-index: -1;
}

.top {
  top: 33%;
  bottom: 51.5%;
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: SlateBlue;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -.5rem 3rem white) blur(0.5rem);
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50% / 80% 80% 20% 20%;
  background: white;
  filter: blur(.8rem);
  transform: scale(2);
}

.fire_red::before,
.fire_red::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 52%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(.9) rotate(45deg);
  background: OrangeRed;
}

.fire_red::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_orange::before,
.fire_orange::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 48.5%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.85) scaleY(0.8) rotate( 45deg);
  background: orange;
}

.fire_orange::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_yellow::before,
.fire_yellow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 44.5%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.75) scaleY(0.6) rotate( 45deg);
  background: gold;
}

.fire_yellow::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire_white::before,
.fire_white::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  padding-top: 102%;
  bottom: 40%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.4) scaleY(0.4) rotate( 45deg);
  background: white;
}

.fire_white::before {
  filter: blur(2rem);
}

.fire {
  animation-name: fire;
  animation-duration: 3ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fire {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(1deg) scaleY(1.05);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) scaleY(0.90);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="fire">
    <div class="fire_red"></div>
    <div class="fire_orange"></div>
    <div class="fire_yellow"></div>
    <div class="fire_white"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```